# Decrypting a base64 string iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I’m trying to decrypt a string thats coming from the server. For example griDE3DgHKa3PDNir8kJvw== is should decrypt to “1”

This is how the key is generated in Java from Service side

```
byte[] salt = new byte[]{172, 137, 25, 56, 156, 100, 136, 211, 84, 67,       96, 10, 24, 111, 112, 137, 3};
int iterations = 1024;
var rfc2898 =
new  
System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes("sOme*ShaREd*SecreT", salt, iterations);
byte[] key = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);
String keyB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
System.Console.WriteLine("Key: " + keyB64);
```

This is how the string is encrypted

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("IV:" + Base64.encode(iv));
System.out.println("Cipher text:" + Base64.encode(ciphertext));
```

I came across this NSData category that encrypts and decrypts but I could not understand everything clearly.

```
- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv {
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
if (iv) {
    [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      keyPtr,
                                      kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                      ivPtr,
                                      [self bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}
free(buffer);
return nil;
```

}

We are using AES128 algorithm, CBC mode with PKCS5 padding. Can anyone help me out?

I know the example is using ECB mode and PKCS7 padding, but I couldn't find they required mode anywhere to replace.

This is how I try to decode

```
NSData *cipherData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Text
                                                 options:0];
NSString *plainText  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[cipherData AES128DecryptedDataWithKey:key] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decrypt AES128+base64: %@", plainText);
```

Comment: And what about the "base64" bit in the title?  What bearing does that have on your question?

Comment: the one I receive from the server is a base64 encoded string.

Comment: But I didn't notice you decoding it.  Is that what you want help with?

Comment: First decode your Base64 string to bytes.  Then use the bytes as the key.  Do this in two steps, and check byte-for-byte matching at both steps.

Comment: okay hold on, let me update

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) answer, PKCS#5 padding is simply PKCS#7 padding restricted to 8 byte block size. Also, from comments to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/can-aes-use-pkcs5-padding) answer it seems that `Java` internally uses PKCS#7 padding when specified cipher as `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`.

From documentation in [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h) to `CommonCryptor`, `CBC` is default block mode.

As conclusion, you should be fine using

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr,
                                      kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                      ivPtr,
                                      [self bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
```

Comment: What is the IV for your example cipher text?

Comment: its null initially, which i think should use all zeros as default

Comment: And key? I am trying to debug decryption.

Comment: key is "sOme * ShaREd * SecreT" without space

Comment: that is shared secret, not key. Key is derived from it via first chunk of code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to separate the iv from the encrypted data.
2. You need to convert the Base64 encoded strings to data.
3. You need to know if the key is, 128, 192 or 256 bytes and explicitly set it. The Java code may be inferring the key size from the supplied key length. It appears that it is 128-bits (16-bytes) from the line `byte[] key = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);`
4. Remove the `kCCOptionECBMode` option, CBC mode is being used which is CBC mode.

You will need to re-work the code to match the Java code, mainly WRT Base64 encoding.